# GIt Local setup with Maven and Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, git, maven, github

I got a private github account setup via github.com and on it I created a repository folder called projectX, the https i something like "https://github.com//ProjectX.git".  Now on my machine (Mac Capitan), via the eclipse "neon",  I also created a maven project called "projectX".
  Question:
  How do I configure my local projectX with git so that I can check it into my github projectX?
  Would you give me the instructions step by step?
  Thanks a lot!
  J.N

Comment: Your question is too broad to be answered succinctly, but if you open to using the command line, then you can a) install Git locally, b) change to the top level directory of your project and type `git init`, c) configured your account and ssh settings, and finally d) `git push origin master` and then you are good to go.

Comment: Here is a link to a tutorial which can get you started: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/setting-up-a-repository/git-clone